# Unable to install add-ons on Ubuntu Software (Genome)

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to install Oracle VM Virtualbox but it's not installing. There's no error message. It seems my disk has no more space so I tried to move other big folders to other disk, but still it doesn't install. I tried the following command line on my terminal but still it doesn't install.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Please see this link for the image:

https://snipboard.io/WGVr2g.jpg

https://snipboard.io/ucjgot.jpg

What does it mean? How to fix it?